# Is there any api for Microsoft Global Address list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, office365apis

I would like to get the name of a user from the global address list, using their email address. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) in particular [Get Contact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151605.aspx) operation allows to access contacts from Global Address List:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/mytenantdomain/contacts?api-version=2013-04-05 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.windows.net
```

Follow [Accessing Azure Active Directory Graph Information](http://azure.microsoft.com/fi-fi/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-aad-graph-info/) article that demonstrates how to consume Graph REST API, in particular:

- how to perform authentication with Azure Active Directory
- perform CRUD operations via [Graph REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh974478.aspx)